# illegal base64 data at input byte 6

Tags: python, perl, subprocess

So , i'm passing my parameters(a list and a string) to a perl file from my python file using subprocess , but it throws me a error.

The python code

```
import os 
import subprocess
method = "operation"
data = ['param1', ' ', 'param2', 'LJs+p7l2KmzFWfhRxqAabcHWPHEGq2couwzktlfbpjwDoXb2GrWUGhrDwM3lwyFSK9R9rf6IAAE8szYVn3jBkQ==', ' ', ' ', 'filter_default', 'filter_default', 'filter_default',0,0]

proc = subprocess.Popen("perl"+" "+"file1.pl "+method+" " + " ".join([str(x) for x in data]),shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err = proc.communicate()
```

and while compiling it return's me this

```
illegal base64 data at input byte 6\n
```

Any quick fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your base64 data.  My guess is your Perl script is trying to decode "filter_default", where byte 6 IS invalid base64.

I notice you have spaces in your `data` list, but you are creating the command as one long string.  That isn't going to be seen as blank parameters.  You'll send

```
perl file1.pl operation param1   param2 lJs+p...   filter_default filter_default
```

and the spaces won't be seen.  If you really need to send empty parameters, then just send a list to Popen:

```
import os 
import subprocess
method = "operation"
data = ['param1', ' ', 'param2', 'LJs+p7l2KmzFWfhRxqAabcHWPHEGq2couwzktlfbpjwDoXb2GrWUGhrDwM3lwyFSK9R9rf6IAAE8szYVn3jBkQ==', ' ', ' ', 'filter_default', 'filter_default', 'filter_default']

proc = subprocess.Popen( ["perl", "file1.pl", method] + data,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err = proc.communicate()
```

Comment: In this case it always throws that second argument should contain only strings

Comment: What does?  Popen or your Perl script?  You really haven't been very specific about that, even in the original question.

Comment: My Python code does that , we have debugged the actual issue and it is about the space being not considered

Comment: @RAJ MANI, Who is not considering a space? What does that even mean? Please put some effort. If you have problems with English, all the more reason to clearly demonstrate what you are trying to achieve, something you don't appear to have attempted.

Comment: He is acknowledging what I said; they thought the spaces were being transmitted to the Perl code as separate parameters.  I suspect this question is now finished.